# How to increment URL ID by 1 for each row in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a url pasted in the first row of my spreadsheet like so:

https://www.dfc/players/1/player/overview

How do I automate it so it will go to the second row and show:

https://www.dfc/players/2/player/overview

And so on:

https://www.dfc/players/3/player/overview
https://www.dfc/players/4/player/overview

Without having to do it manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this?

`="https://www.dfc/players/"&ROW()&"/player/overview"`

or this if you want it to be a hyperlink

`=HYPERLINK("https://www.dfc/players/"&ROW()&"/player/overview")`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an impossible one because its answer is closely connected to its purpose, which you don't disclose.

1. If you just want to look at each URL and then move to the next one you would need to specify the time you want to allow yourself for your study.
2. But even if you just want to be flexible in the time allowed you would need to give a signal to the PC when you want to proceed to the next. And that actually is the second, and more likely purpose, to wit, that you have a workflow and you want the row to change in response to your workflow - which you don't disclose.

In the simplest form your workflow would involve just "look -> click" and "look -> click", in a loop, perhaps until the end of the list. But more likely you would want to do more than just look. So, you would look for a click in the procedure you execute on each URL to which you can attach the extra task of serving as a trigger to call up the next. For example, the URL calls up a picture and when the picture is closed the next one is displayed.

Please don't respond to this answer. It's just meant as a big *Discussion*. Instead, modify your question to provide the information required to suggest a solution. In short, design and explain your intended workflow of which changing the URL is a minor part.